# Mocked class is showing as null on unit test execution

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I wrote a unit test as shown below, following an example of another unit test I have seen, but for some reason when I run the test, inside the class I am testing the `serviceProperties` object is shown as `null`, I thought this approach would of given me a mocked value.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Category({ UnitTests.class })
public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    private OAuth2RestTemplate serviceRestTemplate;

    @Mock
    // had to make this static to use inside TestConfiguration
    static
    serviceProperties serviceProperties;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties
    @Import({ PropertiesTestConfiguration.class, RestTestConfiguration.class })
    static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        MyInterface MyInterface() {
            return new MyInterface(serviceProperties);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    MyInterface MyInterface;

    @Test
    public void getServiceResponse_Success() throws ServiceException {

        Mockito.when(serviceProperties.getUrl()).thenReturn("http://test_url");

        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(serviceProperties.getUrl() + VALID_NUMBER + HEADER_ENDPOINT);

        ResponseEntity<String> mockResponseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(mockResponseBody, HttpStatus.OK);

        thrown.none();

        MyInterface.getClaimByClaimId(VALID_CLAIM_NUMBER);
    }

}
```

Comment: You never initialize your `@Mock` fields, you'd need to do that manually as you're using spring. I.e. in a `@Before` method where you call `MockitoAnnotations.init(this);`

Comment: @Lino that seemed to work for serviceProperties but not for my other mock object serviceRestTemplate, any idea why that would be null? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `@Mock` annotation has no effect without annotating the class with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`.